# ctrl+alt+F1 shows on wrong display

Tags: display, tty

I have dual displays: a monitor and a projector. Whenever I want to go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, the TTY is displayed not on my monitor, but instead it is displayed through the projector on the wall. The monitor goes in power saving mode. If the projector is turned off, there is no way I can see anything when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

I tried to switch the cables, but when I do that, the monitor is showing wrong resolution and I can't set the normal one. I just can't look at the screen that way, it hurts my eyes etc. (This is probably because of the DVI to VGA adapter I'm using). BUT when the cables are switched, the TTY DOES show on my monitor.

But that doesn't solve my problem. I want to see the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> screen AND get normal resolution both in my monitor and in my projector.
I'm using Unity on Ubuntu 12.04.